# python instance() or type() cannot get the right result

Tags: python, types, isinstance

Your any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

I have 2 files, like below

file1:

```
import file2

class Foo():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = file2.dummy()
    print("right?", isinstance(foo, Foo))
    print("right?", type(foo)==Foo)
```

file2:

```
import file1

def dummy():
    foo = file1.Foo()
    return foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Actually, I expect that **isinstance(foo, Foo)** is True, **type(foo) == Foo** is also True, but I get two False.
How do I get my expectations?

Comment: Because you have circular imports, I believe file2 re-loads file1 as a distinct module object. I feel there is a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thankes. Yeah, I know that. But how could I fix it?

Comment: Don't use a circular import. Don't use your module as a script. Have a *seperate* file that imports both file1 and file2

Comment: You have two instances of the `file1` module - one registered under the name `file1`, and the other under the name `__main__`. The solution is to separate your library code from executable code. Move your `if __name__ == '__main__':` block into another file.

Comment: Getting rid of the circular import would be a good idea as well, but it's not strictly necessary.